# i am getting some syntax error in this program??? please check it out someonne

Tags: python, string

```
while month<=12:    
    print('Month =' + str(month))

    monthlyPaymentRate=(0.02*bal)
    annualIntersetRate=((18/100)/12)
    balance=((bal-mmp)*(1+annualInterestRate)
    month=++month        
    bal=balance

    m=round(monthlyPaymentRate,2)
    b=round(balance,2)
    print('Minimum monthly payment =' + str(m))
    print('Current balance =' + str(b))
```

Comment: Some error? Specify your error so that others help you

Comment: Your parens are not balanced (ironically), in this line: `balance=((bal-mmp)*(1+annualInterestRate)`. You have three opening but only two closing `)`.

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't support the prefix or postfix `++`/`--` operators from C. You need to express it as `x + 1`:

```
month += 1
```

The whole code is not very "Pythonic" though. You are writing C-style code in Python.